# ActiveAdmin Filter on postgres Array field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, activeadmin

I added the following filter in ActiveAdmin.

```
filter :roles, as: :select, collection Model::ROLES, multiple: true
```

but when i choose the filter value to  search the roles. it gives me following error

```
PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  malformed array literal: "teacher"LINE 1: ...ted" = $1 AND roles" IN('teacher
DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.                                                             ^
```

Any idea ? How we can search/Filter ARRAY field using AA filters? I'm using **Rails 4.2.4,
ruby 2.2.2p95**

Comment: This will require creating a custom [Ransacker](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Using-Ransackers). What is the format of your JSON field? Is it an array of strings like `["admin", "teacher", "student"]`?

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps but there is an [PostgreSQL Array](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/issues/321) issue with some examples.

Answer (score 4):

I came up to a solution slightly different (and inspired by) this one over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45728004/1170086

Mine involves some changes (and prevent breaking `contains` operator in other cases). So, you're going to basically create two initializer files:

This one is for Arel, in order to support `@>` operator (array's contain operator in PG) for a given table column.

```
# config/initializers/arel.rb

module Arel
  class Nodes::ContainsArray < Arel::Nodes::Binary
    def operator
      :"@>"
    end
  end

  class Visitors::PostgreSQL
    private

    def visit_Arel_Nodes_ContainsArray(o, collector)
      infix_value o, collector, ' @> '
    end
  end

  module Predications
    def contains(other)
      Nodes::ContainsArray.new self, Nodes.build_quoted(other, self)
    end
  end
end
```

The other file aims to create a new Ransack predicate but I also decided to support the `:array` type (that's not natively supported in Ransack in terms of predicates).

```
# config/initializers/ransack.rb

module Ransack
  module Nodes
    class Value < Node
      alias_method :original_cast, :cast

      def cast(type)
        return Array(value) if type == :array
        original_cast(type)
      end
    end
  end
end

Ransack.configure do |config|
  config.add_predicate 'contains_array',
    arel_predicate: 'contains',
    formatter: proc { |v| "{#{v.join(',')}}" },
    validator: proc { |v| v.present? },
    type: :array
end
```

And in other to use it. All you need to do is:

```
User.ransack(roles_contains_array: %i[admin manager])
```

Or as a filter in ActiveAdmin (which is my case):

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  # ...
  filter :roles_contains_array, as: :select, collection: User.roles_for_select
  # ...
end
```

I hope it works for you as it worked for me. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a custom ransacker method to first collect the ids you want returned using a regular postgres search, and then return the results based on those ids:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  ransacker :roles,
    formatter: proc { |str|
      data = where("? = ANY (roles)", str).map(&:id)
      data.present? ? data : nil
    } do |parent|
      parent.table[:id]
    end

end
```

If your filter is a select drop-down, then this should work fine. If you have a free-form text box, then make sure to use the "in" predicate:

```
  filter :roles_in, as: :string
```

Answer (score 0):

leandroico solutions works well.

But if you add the predicate with this formatter

`formatter: proc { |v| "{#{v.join(', ')}}" },` (note the space after the comma)

Then you could use the `multiple: true` keyword in the filter input and filter by more than one value:

`filter :roles_contains_array, as: :select, multiple: true, collection: User.roles_for_select`

Answer (score 0):

I used the answer from @leandroico to come up with the below wiki-type approach to doing this.

**How to Create Custom SQL Searches for ActiveAdmin (using Arel and Ransack)**

In ActiveAdmin, filters are declared in `app/admin/model.rb` like:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Model do
  filter 'column_name', label: 'column_name', as: :string
end
```

That will make a searchbox available on the front-end with options to choose between

```
contains
equals
starts with
ends with
```

You can even do something like...

`filter 'column_name_contains', label: 'column_name', as: :string`

...to only have a `contains` type search available on the front-end.

You can also (after defining some custom methods elsewhere) specify other, non-built-in search methods, like:

`filter 'column_name_custom_contains', label: 'column_name', as: :string`

---

The rest of this doc will be about how to define this custom search method, `custom_contains`

Within `config/initializers/arel.rb`, define the following:

```
  module Arel
    # this example of custom_contains will cast the SQL column as ::text and then do a wildcard-wrapped ILIKE

    class Nodes::CustomContains < Arel::Nodes::Binary
      def operator
        '::text ILIKE'.to_sym
      end
    end

    class Visitors::PostgreSQL
      private
      def visit_Arel_Nodes_CustomContains(o, collector)
        infix_value o, collector, '::text ILIKE '
      end
    end

    module Predications
      def custom_contains(column_value)
        column_value = self.relation.engine.column_types[self.name.to_s].type_cast_for_database(column_value)
        column_value = "%#{self.relation.engine.send(:sanitize_sql_like, column_value)}%"  # wrap escaped value with % wildcard
        column_value = Nodes.build_quoted(column_value, self)
        Nodes::CustomContains.new(self, column_value)
      end
    end
  end

  module ActiveRecord::QueryMethods
    def custom_contains(predicates)
      return none if predicates.length == 0
      predicates.map{ |column_name, column_value|
        column_value = table.engine.column_types[column_name.to_s].type_cast_for_database(column_value)
        column_value = "%#{table.engine.send(:sanitize_sql_like, column_value)}%"  # wrap escaped value with % wildcard
        column_value = Arel::Nodes.build_quoted(column_value)
        where Arel::Nodes::CustomContains.new(table[column_name], column_value)
      }.inject(:merge)
    end
  end

  module ActiveRecord::Querying
    delegate :custom_contains, :to => :all
  end
```

Within `config/initializers/ransack.rb`, define the following:

```
  Ransack.configure do |config|
    config.add_predicate(
      'custom_contains',
      arel_predicate: 'custom_contains',
      formatter: proc { |v| v.to_s },
      validator: proc { |v| v.present? },
      type: :string
    )
  end
```

---

The above has accomplished a couple of things:

1) You can use the custom_contains method that was `delegate`'d to `all` ActiveRecord models:

`puts Model.custom_contains(column_name: 'search for me').to_sql`

2) You can use Ransack to search against the Arel predicates that were defined:

`puts Model.ransack(column_name_custom_contains: 'search for me').result.to_sql`

However, in order to do the below in ActiveAdmin...

`filter 'column_name_custom_contains', label: 'column_name', as: :string`

...we must add a scope to `Model` so that there is a method, `column_name_custom_contains`, on `Model`

```
  scope_name = "#{column_name}_custom_contains".to_sym
  unless Model.methods.include?(scope_name)
    Model.scope(
      scope_name,
      ->(value) {
        Model.custom_contains({column_name.to_sym => value})
      }
    )
  end
```

---

Voila!