# How to search array through ransack gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, ransack

I'm using `ransack gem` for searching in rails application. I need to search an array of `email_ids` in `User` table.

Referring to [this](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/issues/321) issue at ransacking, I followed the steps and added this to the initializers folder `ransack.rb`

```
Ransack.configure do |config|
   {
    contained_within_array: :contained_within,
    contained_within_or_equals_array: :contained_within_or_equals,
    contains_array: :contains,
    contains_or_equals_array: :contains_or_equals,
    overlap_array: :overlap
   }.each do |rp, ap|
   config.add_predicate rp, arel_predicate: ap, wants_array: true
  end
end
```

In the rails console, if i do like this:

```
a = User.search(email_contains_array: ['priti@gmail.com'])
```

it produces the sql like this:

```
"SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\" WHERE \"users\".\"deleted_at\" IS NULL AND (\"users\".\"email\" >> '---\n- priti@gmail.com\n')"
```

and gives error like this:

```
  User Load (1.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND ("users"."email" >> '---
- priti@gmail.com
')
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying >> unknown
 LINE 1: ...RE "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND ("users"."email" >> '---
                                                            ^
 HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
 : SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND ("users"."email" >> '---
 - priti@gmail.com
')
```

Expected is this query:

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE ("users"."roles" @> '{"3","4"}')
```

What is wrong am I doing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I met the same problem as you do. I'm using Rails 5, and I need to search an array of `roles` in `User` table

It seems that you have already add `postgres_ext gem` in your gemfile, but it has some problems if you are using it in Rails 5 application.

So it is a choice for you to add a `contain` query in Arel Node by yourself instead of using `postgres_ext gem`

And if you are using other version of Rails, I think it works well too.

I have an `User` model, and an array attribute `roles`. What I want to do is to use `ransack` to search `roles`. It is the same condition like yours.

`ransack` can't search array. 
But `PostgresSQL` can search array like this:

`User.where("roles @> ?", '{admin}').to_sql)`

it produce the sql query like this:

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND (roles @> '{admin}')
```

So what I want to do is to add a similar contains query in `Arel Nodes`

You can do it [this way](https://gist.github.com/iloveivyxuan/7dfbfc40b2e3c658148bbb52075c614f):

```ruby
# app/config/initializers/arel.rb

require 'arel/nodes/binary'
require 'arel/predications'
require 'arel/visitors/postgresql'

module Arel
  class Nodes::ContainsArray < Arel::Nodes::Binary
    def operator
      :"@>"
    end
  end

  class Visitors::PostgreSQL
    private

    def visit_Arel_Nodes_ContainsArray(o, collector)
      infix_value o, collector, ' @> '
    end
  end

  module Predications
    def contains(other)
      Nodes::ContainsArray.new self, Nodes.build_quoted(other, self)
    end
  end
end
```

Because you can custom ransack predicate, 
so add `contains` Ransack predicate like [this](https://gist.github.com/iloveivyxuan/95e6a5c1404227fbe4ad880461bb52c1):

```ruby
# app/config/initializers/ransack.rb

Ransack.configure do |config|
  config.add_predicate 'contains',
    arel_predicate: 'contains',
    formatter: proc { |v| "{#{v}}" },
    validator: proc { |v| v.present? },
    type: :string
end
```

Done!

Now, you can search array:

```
User.ransack(roles_contains: 'admin')
```

The SQL query will be like this:

```
SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\" WHERE \"users\".\"deleted_at\" IS NULL AND (\"users\".\"roles\" @> '{[\"admin\"]}')
```

Yeah!

Comment: I advise you to change `config.add_predicate 'contains'` to `config.add_predicate 'contains_array'`, otherwise you're going to break the other `contains` functionality for others types of columns. Because I followed what you did here and noticed that side effect.

Comment: This would make a great Pull Request to the Ransack gem. https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/issues/897

Answer (score 2):

I achieved this using ransackable scopes.

Where Author has a column "affiliation" consisting of an array of strings.

```
scope :affiliation_includes, ->(str) {where("array_to_string(affiliation,',') ILIKE ?", "%#{str}%")}
def self.ransackable_scopes(auth_object=nil) 
    [:affiliation_includes]
  end
```

then the following works

```
Author.ransack(affiliation_includes:'dresden')
```

The advantage of this over use of postgres '@>' is that it can match substrings within the array, because of the %'s in the where command (get rid of %'s for whole string match). It is also case-insensitive (use LIKE instead of ILIKE for case-sensitive.