# active admin custom filter for serialized attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I have the following models:

```
Class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :profile
end

class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I have skills column in profile which stores an array of skills. I am using rails active admin and on filtering users with skills I faced a problem which is

> PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  malformed array literal: "java"

my code for the filter is:

```
filter :profile_skills, label: 'Skills', as: :string
```

I am not getting what is the problem. please help me out

Comment: I don't know how you register skills array in the database, but if it is an array it should be filtered by array. For example, `filter :profile_skills, label: 'Skills', as: :select, collection: "your list of skills"`

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34250624/activeadmin-filter-on-postgres-array-field .

Answer (score 5):

ActiveAdmin use [ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack) gem for filtering. The simplest way to filter by array using ransack is to define scope in model:

```rb
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  # @!method skills_includes(skill)
  #   @param skill [String]
  #   @return [ActiveRecord::Relation<Profile>]
  scope :where_skills_contains, ->(skill) { where("skills @> ?", "{#{skill}}") }
end
```

Using this scope you can filter profiles by skills like this `Profile. skills_include('java')`.

By default ransack doesn't allow to use scopes for filtering, so you have to [whitelist](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack#using-scopesclass-methods) this scope:

```rb
class Profile
  def self.ransackable_scopes(*)
    %i(where_skills_contains) 
  end
end
```

Now it's possible ransackable scope in a filter:

```rb
filter :where_skills_contains, label: :skills, as: :string
```

Note, you can't name filter (and scope) `skills_contains`, because it will generate completely different query to database.

```rb
> Profile.ransack(where_skills_contains: 'java').result.to_sql 
#=> SELECT "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE (skills @> '{java}')
> Profile.ransack(skills_contains: 'java').result.to_sql
#=> SELECT "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE ("profiles"."skills" ILIKE '{%java%}')
```

Comment: i am getting this error after the changes as u told undefined method `skills_include_contains' for #<Ransack::Search:0x00007fdb9b5df150>

Comment: @Usar I updated answer to work with contains predicate. You can read more about ransack predicates syntax here https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Basic-Searching

Comment: What exactly? Have you tried to isolate the problem? Test if AR scope works. Probably skills field isn’t an array, but serialized to string array. Sharing table schema and model definition may help

Comment: here is my schema:
create_table "jobseeker_profiles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "skills", default: [], array: true
    t.index ["jobseeker_id"], name: "index_jobseeker_profiles_on_jobseeker_id"
  end and i am using postgress so i havnot added serialize :skills, Array as my db is postgress. I am getting this error undefined method `where_skills_contains' for #<Ransack::Search:0x00007fb09631c2b8>

Comment: the answer is correct and should be accepted. except that I omitted `private_class_method` part to get it to work

Comment: Why is this not part of the official documentation? Also, a hint: I've tried this using raw SQL with `find_by_sql()`, which yields an array. Ransack will not take this and insists upon an ActiveRecord::Relation. Thank you so much, I was about to give up on AA.