# What changes need to do to work with rails 7 without postgres_ext

Tags: sql, arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am maintaining a rails `4.2.11` project and using `postgres_ext` as a dependency. Now as we are planning to update to rails 5 and higher. I noticed that `postgres_ext` is not maintained anymore and will not work with rails 5 and above. so I am getting this error in the following SQL query. It seems to be in the array IN query. How to fix it? What are more probable changes I have to do in my project?

```
[2023-01-25T09:10:33.409Z]   1) ChangeRequestActions::DestructionService#destroy_without_transaction when change request have more than one change request action  delete action from change request
[2023-01-25T09:10:33.409Z]      Failure/Error: company.sections.find_or_create_by(section)
[2023-01-25T09:10:33.409Z]
[2023-01-25T09:10:33.409Z]      ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
[2023-01-25T09:10:33.409Z]        PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  malformed array literal: ""
[2023-01-25T09:10:33.409Z]        LINE 1: ..."position" = $4 AND "sections"."block_titles" IN ('', 'Perso...
[2023-01-25T09:10:33.409Z]                                                                     ^
[2023-01-25T09:10:33.409Z]        DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
[2023-01-25T09:10:33.409Z]        : SELECT  "sections".* FROM "sections" WHERE "sections"."company_id" = $1 AND "sections"."name" = $2 AND "sections"."title" = $3 AND "sections"."position" = $4 AND "sections"."block_titles" IN ('', 'Personal Employee Information', 'Employee W4 Form Request', 'VETS/EEO-1 Reporting', 'Asset & Equipment Management')  ORDER BY sections.id LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I can replicate  it: `select array[''] in ('');` . So it means  "sections"."block_titles"  data type is array type.

Comment: @jian how to easily fix it in rails way?

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/GeorgeKaraszi/ActiveRecordExtended is relevant here.

Comment: I don't know how to solve it in ruby way, in the end, the query would be something like `select 
 array [''] <@ array['', 'Personal Employee Information', 'Employee W4 Form Request', 'VETS/EEO-1 Reporting', 'Asset & Equipment Management']`

Comment: May be this Solution works for you with ransack gem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34250624/activeadmin-filter-on-postgres-array-field

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38410076/how-to-search-array-through-ransack-gem/45728004#45728004

this is works for rails 5.0.2

Comment: https://softans.com/question/what-changes-need-to-do-to-work-with-rails-7-without-postgres_ext/#comment-480